# HTML5 behaving strange while working in jsFiddle

Tags: html, semantic-ui

The title is not very speaking. Using the following code, I want the two elements "Search" and "Logout" to be on the same line as the logo, but all right aligned.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ui block top attached header" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="nb_header left aligned two column row">
        <div class="three wide column">
          (Logo)
        </div>
        <div class="thirteen wide right aligned column">
          <div class="">
            <div class="ui action input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
              <button class="ui button">Search</button>

            </div>
            <div class="ui action red button">Logout</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui attached segment">
              ...content...

  </div>
</div>
```

While I'm typing this exact same code into a jsFiddle for this post, I see that there it's behaving as it should. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kr37euu1/4/

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like in my browser:

[image]

For comparison purposes, I'll post another screenshot of the jsFiddle's version:

[image]

Why does it behave differently?

Comment: Look at the full screen version of the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kr37euu1/show/  Does that look right to you?  If so, compare it line by line to your file.

Comment: Your fiddle is missing a lot of CSS I assume. You have a bunch of classes defined, but in the fiddle none of those classes are used. Does your site have styles defined that are not in the fiddle?

Comment: You've put all of your fiddle CSS in the javascript quadrant, none of it is being used.

Comment: you put wrong css instants of Javascript.

Comment: @andi: The fullscreen-version of the fiddle (as well as the small one) does look right to me. And it's actually the same file - line by line. Except that in the fiddle, I don't have the tags `html`, `head` and `body`.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan,@KevinF,@Vijay: You're all right. But my CSS I've added here was used in the content part, which I've cut away to shorten the fiddle. It actually does only little cosmetics and has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @Atmocreations - you don't see the tags `html`, `head`, or `body` in the fullscreen fiddle?  I see them in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. After several changes to the fiddle and my local code, I found that the only remaining difference was the CSS and JS of `semantic-ui`. Using the CDN version 1.12.3 seems to work - even though my local copy also is 1.12.3.

Downloading the minifed versions from the CDN and putting them in my local instance seemed to resolve the problem - why ever.

thanks to you all for the help.